# Overlap adjacent table cell, without showing table behind

Tags: css

I'm trying to move one table cell so it overlaps another table cell. For that I simply set relative position and increase the width of the cell. However it resizes table and shows table itself behind it (green):

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid black;font-family:monospace}
.green{background:lightgreen}
.blue{background:lightblue}
.red{background:pink}

.shift{
  position: relative;
  left: -3ch;
}

.resize
{
  width: 6ch;
}
```

```html
Table should be this size:
<table class="green">
  <tr class="green">
    <td class="blue">BLU</td>
    <td class="red">RED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
Just shift:
<table class="green">
  <tr class="green">
    <td class="blue">BLU</td>
    <td class="red shift">RED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
Shift + resize:
<table class="green">
  <tr class="green">
    <td class="blue">BLU</td>
    <td class="red shift resize">RED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can't use absolute position. So how can I "resize" a cell so it would use it's own assigned space plus cover adjacent cell, without showing the table behind it?

Comment: A `table` probably isn't your best option here. CSS-Grid *might* be an option though.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively positioned element remains in the flow, so you can’t resize it without affecting the flow.

I would use an absolutely positioned pseudo-element to get the effect you are after. And please use a flexbox rather than a table.

```css
.d1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: monospace;
  position: relative;
}

.d1>* {
  padding: 1px 0;
}

.shift{
  position: relative;
  left: -3ch;
}

.resize::after
{
  content: 'RED';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

.green {background:lightgreen;}
.blue {background:lightblue;}
.red {background:pink;}
p {margin-bottom:3px;}
```

```html
<p>Table should be this size:</p>
<div class="d1 green">
  <div class="blue">BLU</div>
  <div class="red">RED</div>
</div>

<p>Just shift:</p>
<div class="d1 green">
  <div class="blue">BLU</div>
  <div class="red shift">RED</div>
</div>

<p>Overlay absolutely-positioned pseudo-element:</p>
<div class="d1 green">
  <div class="blue">BLU</div>
  <div class="red resize">RED</div>
</div>
```